# Nginx 413 HTTP error when uploading a file even with client_max_body_size set to above the file size

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am running nginx as a reverse proxy to a flask application and when attempting to upload a file, i get a 413 error from nginx (request entity too large).

I have added the client_max_body_size into the nginx configuration file and the configuration for the "redirect" to the flask application to no avail.

```
http {

        //NGINX configuration here//
        client_max_body_size 40M;
}

(site https listen)
http {

        //NGINX configuration here/
        client_max_body_size 40M;
}
```

The expected result is that the 413 error only occurs for files above the 40mb set limit but what does happen is nginx throws the 413 error for a 10mb test file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need put `client_max_body_size` at the top off server / location tag

Comment: It is also possible that the error comes from the upstream. For example, for php you should also increase memory_limit and post_max_size, for Django settings FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE and DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.

Comment: yes that also possible... if you upload to mysql, you need to increase max_allowed_packets...

Comment: please mark as an answer... if it solved, it can help other when encounter like your problem...